# wp8 LonglistSelector AnimateTo

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to scroll to the last item on my longlistselector in WP8, using animation. I can see that in wp7, LongListSelector had a AnimateTo method. Now it does no longer. Any advice of how to animate scrolling? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible due to the way the new LongListSelector is implemented. If you really need this animation, you should put your custom  content in a ScrollViewer instead (note that you will lose virtualization and other benefits from doing this, so consider carefully.)

Comment: I want a smooth scrolling from somewhere in the middle of the list to the end of the list. Do you mean I cannot achieve that with the LongListSelector?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use another control.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ScrollTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.scrollto%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) provided in LongListSelector control to navigate to any Item.