# Content transition in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to make some text reading application for Windows Phone 8. I would like to make the user go forward or backward on pages by simply swiping his finger over the screen, but I would like this to be animated like Pivot control. I'm not using pivot control, I'm using a LongList Selector to display the content and it fits well. I have already made the content change on swap but could not animate it. I see the kindle app does something like that for changing the page when you're reading the book, but I believe it not change a real page, just the content.

Anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) animations? I don't know, but maybe so works.

greetings.

Comment: Yes Dachi, they work great for transitions. In my case I want the animation when the content is changed not the page itself

Comment: I found this post about [LonglistSelector AnimateTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180360/wp8-longlistselector-animateto). I think you must animate with a [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) a Container as Grid,Stackpanel, or try if work with a LongList Selector. In Blend is better to do this animations but se that blend generate when making animation is important to change it after if you want. greetings.

Comment: Thank you Dachi, but unfortunately this wont work for me. I need to animated when the content is changed, I cant have the content preloaded to make the animation.